# I'm trying to make sure the code is thread-safe

Tags: multithreading, scala, thread-safety

I have an object which run a process:

```
object MyObject {

  def apply(fullFileName: String, recordId: Long): Unit = Future {
    import scala.sys.process.Process

    Process(s"someProcess $fullFileName").!!
  } onComplete {
    case util.Success(x) => 
      //insert result into db
      //update status in db

    case util.Failure(e) => //log the result
  }
}

def getNextId() = ... //returns the incremented current id from db
```

And its calling, for example:

```
val list = List(...)
list foreach (MyObject(_, getNextId()))
//insert default value into db
```

Assume there won't 2 files with the same name.

Is this code actually thread-safe? It probably is. You ideas? But I'm not sure about `getNextId().`

Comment: getNextId() is a read from a sequence or an autoincrement in database ? so this is threadsafe to do this.

Comment: There is no state mutation in the code you show, so it is impossible to say whether that is thread safe or not. It is also not clear what your threading situation will be; are you having multiple threads, and if so, how are they spawned?

Comment: @0__, the second part of the code is from an Action of Play application. Does this mean there'll be many threads (in case there'll be many requests from the clients at the same time)?

Comment: @twillouer, it reads from db.